# How can I end while loop and skip for loop?

Tags: python, loops

How do I make it where if the user enters 'no' the program won't go through the for loop either. I don't want it to tmpfile.write(line) if the user enters 'no'.

```
def remove():
    coname = raw_input('What company do you want to remove? ') # company name
    f = open('codilist.txt')
    tmpfile = open('codilist.tmp', 'w')
    for line in f:
        if coname.upper() in line:
            while True:
                answer = raw_input('Are you sure you want to remove ' + line.upper() + '?')
                if answer == 'yes':
                    print line.upper() + '...has been removed.'               
                elif answer == 'no':
                    break  # HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                else:
                    print 'Please choose yes or no.'                   
        else:
            tmpfile.write(line)
    else:
        print 'Company name is not listed.'
    f.close()
    tmpfile.close()
    os.rename('codilist.tmp', 'codilist.txt')
```

Comment: That's one case when GOTO is legal.

Answer (score 3):

Set a flag variable and then break out of the while loop. Then in the for loop, check if the flag is set, and then break.

PS: if is **not** a loop

Comment: The final `else` is attached to the `for` - it will trigger if the loop finishes without a `break`.

Comment: @vaisakh: No problem. Edited so I could reverse my downvote (it was locked in)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to create a function that gets user input:

```
def get_yes_or_no(message):
    while True:
        user_in = raw_input(message).lower()
        if user_in in ("yes", "no"):
            return user_in
```

And modify your original function like so:

```
def remove():
    coname = raw_input('What company do you want to remove? ') # company name
    f = open('codilist.txt')
    tmpfile = open('codilist.tmp', 'w')
    for line in f:
        if coname.upper() in line:
            answer = get_yes_or_no('Are you sure you want to remove ' + line.upper() + '?')
            #answer logic goes here              
        else:
            tmpfile.write(line)
    else:
        print 'Company name is not listed.'
    f.close()
    tmpfile.close()
    os.rename('codilist.tmp', 'codilist.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has exceptions, which you can use in place of a GOTO type of construction.

```
class Breakout(Exception):
    pass

def remove():
    coname = raw_input('What company do you want to remove? ') # company name
    f = open('codilist.txt')
    tmpfile = open('codilist.tmp', 'w')
    try:
        for line in f:
            if coname.upper() in line:
                while True:
                    answer = raw_input('Are you sure you want to remove ' + line.upper() + '?')
                    if answer == 'yes':
                        print line.upper() + '...has been removed.'
                    elif answer == 'no':
                        raise Breakout()
                    else:
                        print 'Please choose yes or no.'
            else:
                tmpfile.write(line)
        else:
            print 'Company name is not listed.'
    except Breakout:
        pass

    f.close()
    tmpfile.close()
    os.rename('codilist.tmp', 'codilist.txt')
```

Notice where in exception is raised in the middle there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the whole `for` loop in a function and use `return` to get out of it:

```
def find_and_remove(f,coname,tmpfile):
    for line in f:
        if coname.upper() in line:
            while True:
                answer = raw_input('Are you sure you want to remove ' + line.upper() + '?')
                if answer == 'yes':
                    print line.upper() + '...has been removed.'               
                elif answer == 'no':
                    return  # HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                else:
                    print 'Please choose yes or no.'                   
        else:
            tmpfile.write(line)
    else:
        print 'Company name is not listed.'

def remove():
    coname = raw_input('What company do you want to remove? ') # company name
    f = open('codilist.txt')
    tmpfile = open('codilist.tmp', 'w')
    find_and_remove(f,coname,tmpfile)
    f.close()
    tmpfile.close()
    os.rename('codilist.tmp', 'codilist.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an infinite loop and `break`ing when you skip a line, differentiate between the three cases (skip, remove, and invalid answer) using a flag in the loop condition. You set the flag to exit the loop in the skip case, break in the remove case, and leave the flag as-is in the invalid answer case. This lets you use the `else` clause of the `while` (which is triggered if the `while` exits because the condition became false) to detect the skip case. From there, you can jump ahead to the next iteration of the `for` loop using `continue` (or skip all the rest of the lines using `break` - it isn't quite clear from the question which you intend, but the difference is change of keyword):

```
for line in f:
    if coname.upper() in line:
        answered = False
        while not answered:
            answer = raw_input('Are you sure you want to remove ' + line.upper() + '?')
            if answer == 'yes':
                print line.upper() + '...has been removed.'
                break
            elif answer == 'no':
                answered = True  # HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            else:
                print 'Please choose yes or no.'
        else:
            continue
    else:
        tmpfile.write(line)
else:
    print 'Company name is not listed.'
```